# Refining Bash loop

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, sh

Hello Stackoverflow community,

Please forgive me for my naïveté, but I have a basic loop script running a more complex script that is looking to a text file for the inputs that I have as an array. I have it working, I  guess, but I know this can be ran better and more automated.

Here is the text file my script looks to;

```
2014;14204;
2015;15042;
2015;15062;
...
end;
```

Here is the bash script I run as a loop;

```
{ while IFS=';' read  YEAR1 PROJ1 YEAR2 PROJ2 YEAR3 PROJ3 fake
    do 
        { echo "$YEAR1" | egrep '^#|^ *$' ; } > /dev/null && continue 
            $local/script.sh \
                --forinput1 $YEAR1/$PROJ1  \
                --forinput2 $YEAR2/$PROJ2  \
                --forinput3 $YEAR3/$PROJ3  \
    done 
} < textFile.txt
```

I have done some research myself and have found somethings I thought would work but haven't been able to properly implement into this. If you could some me some pointers I would appreciate it.

Edited:
I do apologize, so the script does recognize the text file as such:

```
YEAR1;PROJ1;
YEAR2;PROJ2;
YEAR3;PROJ3;
```

Using the ";" as its separator. It does run in a loop until the last variable it done. However, for it function I need to add to the text file extra lines

```
YEAR4;PROJ4;
YEAR5;PROJ5;
end;
```

then add the script

```
{ while IFS=';' read  YEAR1 PROJ1 YEAR2 PROJ2 YEAR3 PROJ3 YEAR4 PROJ4 YEAR5 PROJ5 fake
    do 
        { echo "$YEAR1" | egrep '^#|^ *$' ; } > /dev/null && continue 
            $local/script.sh \
                --forinput1 $YEAR1/$PROJ1  \
                --forinput2 $YEAR2/$PROJ2  \
                --forinput3 $YEAR3/$PROJ3  \
                --forinput4 $YEAR4/$PROJ4  \
                --forinput5 $YEAR5/$PROJ5  \
    done 
} < textFile.txt
```

What I am hoping to accomplish is adding the variables in the array but not having to add the extra syntax into the script

This is broken but I guess what I am looking along the lines of

```
{ while IFS=';' read -a YEAR PROJ < textFile.txt
for ((i = 0; i < "${#YEAR[@]};${#PROJ[@]}"; i++)); do
{ echo "$YEAR[$i]" | egrep '^#|^ *$' ; } > /dev/null && continue 
                $local/script.sh \
                    --forinput[$i] ${YEAR[$i]}/${PROJ[$i]}  \
        done 
    }
```

Comment: The `read` command you've included would seem to expect input with at least six fields per line rather than two. If that's really your input, and you have multi-line records, then you should perhaps include a few more records and describe how to differentiate between them. Also, please include your intended output. We could improve the style of the script, but it would be much better to know what you want out of it.

Comment: Your loop will run exactly once, because `egrep` is going to consume the rest of `textFile.txt` before `read` runs again.

Comment: Do you really want to call script.sh once with all the arguments from the file? Or do you have some other intent?

Comment: @chapner, really? egrep is taking its input from the echo statement, then it exits.

Comment: You can move the `egrep '^#|^ *$'` test outside the loop: `while ..;do..done < <(egrep -v '^#|^ *(;|$)' texttFile.txt)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your input file contains groups of 3 lines each with 2 fields, not lines of 6 fields.

```
$ cat file
y1a;p1a;
y2a;p2a;
y3a;p3a;
y1b;p1b;
y2b;p2b;
y3b;p3b;
```

Then, you can put multiple read commands as the while "condition":

```
while
     IFS=';' read year1 proj1 x
     IFS=';' read year2 proj2 x
     IFS=';' read year3 proj3 x
do
    echo script \
        --forinput1 "$year1/$proj1" \
        --forinput2 "$year2/$proj2" \
        --forinput3 "$year3/$proj3"
done < file
```

```
script --forinput1 y1a/p1a --forinput2 y2a/p2a --forinput3 y3a/p3a
script --forinput1 y1b/p1b --forinput2 y2b/p2b --forinput3 y3b/p3b
```

However, this does not handle comments and blank lines. This version executes the script after the 3rd non-(comment/blank) line

```
$ cat file
# set 1
y1a;p1a;
y2a;p2a;
y3a;p3a;

# set 2
y1b;p1b;
y2b;p2b;
y3b;p3b;
```

and

```
n=0
args=()
while IFS=';' read year project x; do
    { [[ $year == *([[:blank:]])"#"* ]] || [[ $year == *([[:blank:]]) ]]; } && continue
    ((n++))
    args+=( "--forinput$n" "$year/$project" )
    if (( n == 3 )); then 
        echo script "${args[@]}"
        args=()
        n=0
    fi
done < file
```

```
script --forinput1 y1a/p1a --forinput2 y2a/p2a --forinput3 y3a/p3a
script --forinput1 y1b/p1b --forinput2 y2b/p2b --forinput3 y3b/p3b
```

---

Another approach to handle arbitrary records per group:

```
$ cat file
# set 1
y1a;p1a;
y2a;p2a;
y3a;p3a;
y4a;p4a;
y5a;p5a;
end;

# set 2
y1b;p1b;
y2b;p2b;
y3b;p3b;
end;

$ grep -Pv '^\s*(#|$)' file | awk -F"\n" -v RS="\nend;\n" -v OFS=, '{
    cmd = "script.sh"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        n = split($i, a, /;/)
        cmd = sprintf( "%s --forinput%d \"%s/%s\"", cmd, i, a[1], a[2])
    }
    print cmd
}'
script.sh --forinput1 "y1a/p1a" --forinput2 "y2a/p2a" --forinput3 "y3a/p3a" --forinput4 "y4a/p4a" --forinput5 "y5a/p5a"
script.sh --forinput1 "y1b/p1b" --forinput2 "y2b/p2b" --forinput3 "y3b/p3b"
```

That uses `grep` to filter out the comments and blank lines. Then `awk` comes it to format the commands:

- `RS` is the **record** separator, using the `end;` line
- `-F"\n"` sets the **field** separator to a newline
- then we iterate over the number of fields (`NF`) to construct the command you want to run, and print it out.

To actually execute it, pipe the awk output to `| sh`

Comment: Thanks Glenn, Well honestly it is only holding the one field and what I am trying to have is that one field be able to hold as many lines as I need. I am testing out your `n=0
args=()
while IFS=';' read year project x; do
    { [[ $year == *([[:blank:]])"#"* ]] || [[ $year == *([[:blank:]]) ]]; } && continue
    ((n++))
    args+=( "--forinput$n" "$year/$project" )
    if (( n == 3 )); then 
        echo script "${args[@]}"
        args=()
        n=0
    fi
done < file` but am running into `line 11: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `(['` can you clarify?

Comment: Is the `end;` line in your file to delimit groups of records?

Comment: Also, for the "unexpected token" error, are you using `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` or some other shell?

Comment: I like your triple-read approach. When I had thought of such a solution, I would handle special lines outside the loop (` <(egrep -v '^#|^ *(;|$)' texttFile.txt)`).

Comment: Thanks, Walter A.

Comment: @csiket715, `sh` cannot handle arrays. You need bash/ksh/zsh for that.

Comment: @glennjackman I have tried all three `/bin/bash`, `/bin/ksh`, and `/bin/zsh` and all are failing on `{ [[ $YEAR == *([[:blank:]])"#"* ]] || [[ $YEAR == *([[:blank:]]) ]]; }` ... `syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token ('
 syntax error near *(['`. I just want to confirm do I need to put anything in for `*([[:blank:]])`?

Comment: No, that is an extended pattern. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b, the paragraph discussing `==` -- what version of bash are you using?

Comment: version 3.2.57(1)-release

Comment: OK, for bash v3.2, it looks like you have to explicitly enable extended patterns with `shopt -s extglob`

Comment: ok figured out if I got rid of the `*()` from  `*([[:blank:]])"#"*` it works

Comment: and I was able to get your expected output thank you @glennjackman

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that each inputline has 6 fields, what might lead to code like

```
sed -nr 's#([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);#$local/script.sh --forinput \1/\2 --forinput \3/\4 --forinput \5/\6#p' textFile.txt
# or shorter
f='([^;]*;)'
sed -nr 's#'$f$f$f$f$f$f'#$local/script.sh --forinput \1/\2 --forinput \3/\4 --forinput \5/\6#p' textFile.txt
```

When you have to combine 3 lines for the input, you should not try to be smart.

```
# Don't do this
cat textFile.txt | paste -d'X' - - - | tr -d 'X'
# Trying to make
sed -nr 's#'$f$f$f$f$f$f'#$local/script.sh --forinput \1/\2 --forinput \3/\4 --forinput \5/\6#p' <(cat textFile.txt | paste -d'X' - - - | tr -d 'X')
```

After proudly presenting the code, you see you will have to make the code even worse, when the second line is a comment (starts with '#'). You need to replace `cat textFile.txt` with `grep -Ev '^#|^ *$' testFile.txt`.

When you need to relate different lines, take a look at `awk`.
The solution without checks is

```
awk -F';' '{line++}
{param=param " --forinput " $1 "/" $2}
line==3 {print "$local/script.sh" param ; param=""; line=0}
' textFile.txt
```

You can add all kind of checks.